# How to declare an empty array in Rust like with make() in Go?

Tags: rust

In Go I can declare a new EMPTY slice using:

```golang
players := make([]Player, 0, len(player_list))
```

How to do this in Rust?

I tried with:

```rust
players = vec!(Player; 0; player_list.len())
```

but this is wrong because I only need to declare an empty array, not new one with one Player already inside.

How to?

Comment: You should probably directly use the `Vec` type and not the `vec!` macro.

Comment: If I am not mistaken (I am very new to rust), if you want to create a new empty vector with already allocated space for your players, you should use : `players = Vec::with_capacity(player_list.len())`

Comment: How? I would like to understand how to add an element after the declaration too...

Comment: To add elements after declaration, you can use `players.push(player)`.

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret is completely correct. That aside the `vec![]` invocation makes no sense, `vec!` just takes a value and a length, it doesn't need a type. You also need `let players` to declare that variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an empty vector of size n, and not fill it with anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989694/create-an-empty-vector-of-size-n-and-not-fill-it-with-anything)

Comment: @Mate they don't actually want a vector of *length* n, Go's `make` takes a length and a capacity, if the length is nonzero, the array gets filled with zero-values. Here the length is 0: `players := make(/*[]T*/[]Player, /*length*/0, /*capacity*/len(player_list))` so it's just preallocating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, array is not a vector and zero-sized array would be similar to `()`, so I guess you need vectors. To create an empty vector use [`Vec::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new) like this:

```rust
let mut players = Vec::<Player>::new();
```

To create a vector with custom capacity use [`Vec::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity).